# Усовршенствовать поиск

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

у меня возник вопрос, как бы дополнить свой поиск по базе данных. Справа на сайте есть блок-меню, там разные ссылки на категории блюд (эти ссылки пустые) и есть строка поиска, которая ищет по базе данных (БД) блюда из этих же категорий. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любую категорию из правого блока выполнялся поиск `/search` из БД. Грубо говоря мне интересно можно ли сделать как-то так, чтобы `def search():`  искал не только вручную введенную в строку поиска категорию `search_string = request.form['input_query']` , но и просто по нажатии на соответствующую ссылку. [На гитхабе](https://github.com/artisakov/vigilant-journey)

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_string = request.form['input_query']
        con = sqlite3.connect('C:/FFlaskApplication/diacompanion.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (name) name ,_id FROM"
                    " receipts WHERE category LIKE ? GROUP BY name", ('%{}%'.format(search_string),))
        result = cur.fetchall()

        return render_template('index.html', result=result, name=current_user.username)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route('/searchlink/<string:search_string>')
def searchlink(search_string):
    con = sqlite3.connect('C:/FFlaskApplication/diacompanion.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (name) name ,_id FROM"
                " receipts WHERE category LIKE ? GROUP BY name", ('%{}%'.format(search_string),))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    print('Были выбраны блюда')

    return render_template('index.html', result=result, name=current_user.username)
```

```
<a class='sidemenu' href="{{ url_for('searchlink', search_string = 'Блюда из бобовых')}}">
Блюда из бобовых
</a>
```